# Which talend product to download?

Tags: talend

Which talend tool should i download . I need to use enterprise technologies like REST/SOAP/JSON/XML/JDBC/SFTP/XSD (Oracle).

My use cases are :

1. Exposing services(REST/SOAP)
2. Reading from file like MT940,CSV,flat files and storing in database (Oracle)
3. Using SFTP ,File Movements frequently.

What is the difference between TALEND Data integration and Talend ESB.

Currently i have download Talend Big Data Open studio .
Will this suffice?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are wanting to do with it. I'm thinking Talend Data Integrator, the free version should suffice, if all you want to do is pull data.